# Ubuntu 16.04 Graphics issues intel HD 620

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10 on the new Lenovo Yoga 910 (kaby lake)

I'm experiencing both flickering and tearing of the display that makes the laptop unusable. The temporary work around has been to reduce the resolution, and the issues stop. I've tried updating with the latest Intel drivers, to no avail. Anyone else find a solution for full resolution?

Graphics chipset is the Intel HD 620.

Comment: Kaby Lake is new, and drivers are very prone to bugs currently. Use the resolution workaround and submit bugs in [Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: A solution I had is written here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004375/screen-flickering-ubuntu-16-04-intel-graphics-620/1018149#1018149

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it (razer blade stealth i7 7500U kaby lake HD 620 graphic card with 2560x1440 screen).

I opened a bug on the drm intel here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99159 .

A patch has been made to the kernel yesterday (4.9+ which means it will land in the 4.10 release).

In order to fix it, you need to have this patch in your kernel/drm intel. Either you wait for the 4.10 release, or recompile from the drm-tip kernel.