# Screen flickering Ubuntu 16.04 Intel graphics 620

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I have recently switched to Ubuntu and my screen flickers when I watch videos. I have searched the forum a lot, tried the Intel graphics tool, modified the grub file and it's still flickering. I have read that some bug associated with Intel graphics got fixed in kernel version 4.10 and up so I don't know what the problem is.
My laptop is a Dell Latitude 7280, i7, Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2), Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel version 4.13
Also, I tried connecting to a different screen with HDMI and it flickers there too.
Thanks.

Comment: I've found the same problem on a Dell Latitude 7280 with Ubuntu 20.04, but it only occurs when the CPU is idle -- if you force it to be busy (e.g. run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null`) then it doesn't flicker.  Haven't found a better fix yet than this hacky workaround, and the only current answer doesn't work for me, but if I do find a fix then I'll answer this question!

Answer (score 0):

I had been experiencing the same problem with my Dell Vostro 5370 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

This is how I solved it:

1. Go to "Software & Updates" application
2. Under "Additional Drivers" tab, you should find "Intel Corporation: Unknown" section.
3. Choose "Do not use the device"

[image: Do not use DKMS driver from oem]

Because DKMS will "pollute" your kernel until you purge the kernel using apt-get. The way I did is:

1. reboot to an older working kernel (to choose different kernel in boot menu, you might want to check out [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time))
2. use `$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image` to check what kernel you have installed
3. use similar commands to `# apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-73-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-73-generic` to purge linux completely
4. install latest kernel back by version if you wish: `# apt-get install linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic`
5. Reboot your computer and good luck!

If you are not so lucky that you have a functional kernel, you would probably either work under the flicker screen or use the old console without GUI.