# Flashing screen in Acer, Intel HD Graphics

Tags: 16.04, graphics, screen, intel

I have an Acer TravelMate X349 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit.
The graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
The processor is Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4.

The problem: after some time of using in a session, the screen flashes, usually after switching to another window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to mark it as duplicate, but check the answer I have given here:

[Screen flickering Ubuntu 16.04 Intel graphics 620](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004375/screen-flickering-ubuntu-16-04-intel-graphics-620/1018149#1018149)

Comment: Thanks but I don't have anything under "Additional Drivers" unfortunately, it just says "No additional drivers available"

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. You may want to checkout if it is indeed due to dkms, by checking out how to use dkms from this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73091/list-of-packages-managed-by-dkms